# Python CSV: Remove quotes from value

Tags: python, csv

I have a process where a CSV file can be downloaded, edited then uploaded again. On the download, the CSV file is in the correct format, with no wrapping double quotes

```
1, someval, someval2
```

When I open the CSV in a spreadsheet, edit and save, it adds double quotes around the strings

```
1, "someEditVal", "someval2"
```

I figured this was just the action of the spreadsheet (in this case, openoffice). I want my upload script to remove the wrapping double quotes. I cannot remove all quotes, just incase the body contains them, and I also dont want to just check first and last characters for double quotes.

Im almost sure that the CSV library in python would know how to handle this, but not sure how to use it...

EDIT
When I use the values within a dictionary, they turn out as follows

```
{'header':'"value"'}
```

Thanks

Comment: The quotation marks are generally considered to be allowed in CSV files.  Are you sure you have to remove them?

Comment: Yeah, Im using them in a processing script putting them into a dictionary,and they turn out like this {'header':'"value"'}

Comment: Open office calc 3.2 DOESN'T put spaces after the commas. What version are you using?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For you example, the following works:

```
import csv
writer = csv.writer(open("out.csv", "wb"), quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
reader = csv.reader(open("in.csv", "rb"), skipinitialspace=True)
writer.writerows(reader)
```

You might need to play with the dialect options of the CSV reader and writer -- see the [documentation of the `csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect).

Comment: QUOTE_NONE works when downloading/creating the CSV, which is great! But my problem is when I edit the csv (which is where the double quotes are added in) and upload it again. Thanks for the helpful answer though!

Comment: The code I gave is not for parsing the file -- it is for converting your "wrong" file to a "correct" one.  If you just want to read it, use only the reader, not the writer.  Maybe you just needed `skipinitialspace=True`?

Comment: QUOTE_NONE is NOT a good idea if as the OP said he has `"` in the content.

Comment: @John: The OP wants these quotes to be removed -- this is what the script does.  I'm confused by your comment.

Comment: There appears to be some evidence that what the OP wants is not what the OP needs :-)

Comment: This script works great when I have few number of rows. But when I have a lot of row, it seems that some of the rows are not printed out by the end. Do you have an idea why? Is there any buffering related thing that I need to worry about?

Comment: @SvenMarnach yes, it is indeed related to caching. So I put the script in a file.py and invoke it like that. Problem solved. Good stuff.

Answer (score 14):

Thanks to everyone who was trying to help me, but I figured it out. When specifying the reader, you can define the quotechar

```
csv.reader(upload_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
```

This handles the wrapping quotes of strings.

Comment: The two parameters you pass are just the defaults -- you can simply omit them!  And this won't parse the example data in your question -- this will only work with `skipinitialspace=True`.

Comment: ah ok, thanks Sven! I omitted those params and it still works, thanks for the help. I used the reader using the default params. If you would like to post as an answer ill mark it

Comment: If this works, you didn't post the real data in your question.  As for the data in the question, this does not work.

Comment: It turns out the original reader I was using had the quotechar defined as a pipe... (I am pretty new to stackoverflow, should I delete the question as this was my mistake?)

Comment: Up to you... Most certainly it is not very useful to keep it.

Answer (score 10):

For **Python 3**:

```
import csv
writer = csv.writer(open("query_result.csv", "wt"), quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='\\')
reader = csv.reader(open("out.txt", "rt"), skipinitialspace=True)
writer.writerows(reader)
```

The original answer gives this error under Python 3. Also See this SO for detail: [csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515053/csv-error-iterator-should-return-strings-not-bytes)

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "remove_quotes.py", line 11, in 
>       writer.writerows(reader)
>   _csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Comment: why is there `'rt'`mode for `writer` and `wt` for `reader`?
I also think that you should set `escapechar`

Comment: @Zangetsu That's a good call. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll update the answer.