# csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Sample.csv contains the following:

```
NAME    Id   No  Dept
Tom     1    12   CS
Hendry  2    35   EC
Bahamas 3    21   IT
Frank   4    61   EE
```

And the Python file contains the following code:

```
import csv
ifile  = open('sample.csv', "rb")
read = csv.reader(ifile)
for row in read :
    print (row)
```

When I run the above code in Python, I get the following exception:

> File "csvformat.py", line 4, in 
>       for row in read :
>   _csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 250, accepted):

You open the file in text mode.

More specifically:

```
ifile  = open('sample.csv', "rt", encoding=<theencodingofthefile>)
```

Good guesses for encoding is "ascii" and "utf8". You can also leave the encoding off, and it will use the system default encoding, which tends to be UTF8, but may be something else.

Comment: Just want to add to this that if you get encoding errors when you try reading/writing from/to a CSV file, adding a particular encoding can help. I just fixed this bug on mine by adding "encoding = 'utf-8'".

Answer (score 121):

The reason it is throwing that exception is because you have the argument `rb`, which opens the file in binary mode. Change that to `r`, which will by default open the file in [text mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Your code:

```
import csv
ifile  = open('sample.csv', "rb")
read = csv.reader(ifile)
for row in read :
    print (row)
```

New code:

```
import csv
ifile  = open('sample.csv', "r")
read = csv.reader(ifile)
for row in read :
    print (row)
```

Comment: changing argument `rb` to `r` perfectly solved my issue. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 50):

In Python3, `csv.reader` expects, that passed iterable returns strings, not bytes. Here is one more solution to this problem, that uses `codecs` module:

```
import csv
import codecs
ifile  = open('sample.csv', "rb")
read = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(ifile, 'utf-8'))
for row in read :
    print (row)
```

Comment: Note that this option isn't the safest. If you can use TextIOWrapper, you should.

Issue descriptions:
[iterdecode eats empty strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43904544/1834570)
[iterdecode isn't safe with multi-byte characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20602013/1834570)

The solution:
[TextIOWrapper on a csv stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51152810/1834570)

Comment: Thanks! was facing this issue on Python3.

Comment: @Grigoriy Mikhalkin My adulation goes to for the codecs solution, it just resolve an issue streaming a csv file stored in S3, and csv.reader did not like it without codecs.

Answer (score 33):

Your problem is you have the `b` in the `open` flag. 
The flag `rt` (read, text) is the default, so, using the context manager, simply do this:

```
with open('sample.csv') as ifile:
    read = csv.reader(ifile) 
    for row in read:
        print (row)
```

The context manager means you don't need generic error handling (without which you may get stuck with the file open, especially in an interpreter), because it will automatically close the file on an error, or on exiting the context.

The above is the same as:

```
with open('sample.csv', 'r') as ifile:
    ...
```

or

```
with open('sample.csv', 'rt') as ifile:
    ...
```

Comment: The `with` statement a.k.a. the context manager has nothing to do with this question, at all!

Comment: @RayLuo When I'm demonstrating file handling, I'm also going to demonstrate the best practices around it. I do that fairly consistently. If you're new to Python, and you get stuck in an interactive session with a file you can't do anything with, you would have appreciated my advice...

Answer (score 11):

I had this error when running an old python script developped with Python 2.6.4

When updating to 3.6.2, I had to remove all 'rb' parameters from **open** calls in order to fix this csv reading error.

Answer (score 2):

This is a GOTCHA in Django. The open that comes with filefield always opens the file in byte mode as far as I can tell. You need to open with Python's open instead.

So with avccont_datafile being an instance of a model with a field called     datafile = django.db.models.FileField(), The following code....

```
with avccount_datafile.datafile.file.open('rt') as fp:
    self.avc_data = csv.DictReader(fp)
```

gives the error

```
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

but this fixes it

```
filename = avccount_datafile.datafile.file.name
with open(filename, 'rt') as fp:
        self.avc_data = csv.DictReader(fp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in django

```
import csv
import io
csv_file = = open('sample.csv', "rb")
file = csv_file.read().decode('utf-8')
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(file))
for row in csv_reader:
    print(row)
```