# Convert binary input stream to text mode

Tags: python, file-io, io, stream, python-3.x

I am trying to read a bzip2-compressed CSV file in Python 3.2. For an uncompressed CSV file, this works:

```
datafile = open('./file.csv', mode='rt')
data = csv.reader(datafile)
for e in data:    # works
    process(e)
```

The problem is that **`BZ2File` only supports creating a binary stream**, and in Python 3, [`csv.reader` accepts only text streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515053/csv-error-iterator-should-return-strings-not-bytes). (The same issue occurs with gzip and zip files.)

```
datafile = bz2.BZ2File('./file.csv.bz2', mode='r')
data = csv.reader(datafile)
for e in data:    # error
    process(e)
```

In particular, the indicated line throws the exception `_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)`.

I've also tried `data = csv.reader(codecs.EncodedFile(datafile, 'utf8'))`, but that doesn't fix the error.

How can I wrap the binary input stream so that it can be used in text mode??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me:

```
import codecs, csv
f = codecs.open("file.csv", "r", "utf-8")
g = csv.reader(f)
for e in g:
    print(e)
```

In the case of BZ2:

```
import codecs, csv, bz2
f = bz2.BZ2File("./file.csv.bz2", mode="r")
c = codecs.iterdecode(f, "utf-8")
g = csv.reader(c)
for e in g:
    print(e)
```

Comment: And how exactly did you intend on using this with a bz2-compressed file?

Comment: @vz0: The last detail to be checked is if the interpretation of newlines works as expected (i.e. no interpretation).  In other words, if the newline sequences can be contained inside the quoted values, an uncompressed CSV would use the `open(fname, 'r', newlines='')`.  It is likely, it works correctly.  Can you try?