# Text mode adapter for binary (or text) mode file

Tags: file, python-3.x

I have a method (`parse`) that processes data from an input file, which may have been opened in binary mode. However in some subclasses it would be easier to process the data if the file were opened in text mode. So my question is if theres an easy way to wrap any file to get something that acts as a text mode file.

Note that the solution in ["Convert binary input stream to text mode"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509753/convert-binary-input-stream-to-text-mode) does not really make it as it only produces an iterator (and not a file-like object). Also note that opening the file in text mode in the first place is not an option.

If it simplifies the solution one can assume that the input file is indeed opened in binary mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as the `buffer` argument in `io.TextIOWrapper` is actually an `io.BufferedReader` object (ie file opened in binary mode). This is however not obvious from reading the documentation.

This seem to work if the file is known to be opened in binary mode (instance of `io.RawIOBase` or `io.BufferedIOBase`):

```
srctxt = io.TextIOWrapper(src)
```

It doesn't work however if `src` is already opened in text mode, but it could be tested by checking if it is is an `io.TextIOBase`:

```
if isinstance(src, io.TextIOBase):
    srctxt = src
else:
    srctxt = io.TextIOWrapper(src)
```