# Open file from zip without extracting it in Python?

Tags: python, zip

I am working on a script that fetches a zip file from a URL using tje request library. That zip file contains a csv file. I'm trying to read that csv file without saving it. But while parsing it's giving me this error: `_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)`

```
import csv
import requests
from io import BytesIO, StringIO
from zipfile import ZipFile

response = requests.get(url)
zip_file = ZipFile(BytesIO(response.content))
files = zip_file.namelist()
with zip_file.open(files[0]) as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)

    # _csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

    for row in csvreader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert binary input stream to text mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509753/convert-binary-input-stream-to-text-mode)

Comment: `ZipFile.open` returns a binary stream, but `csv.reader` expects a text stream. You have to add a wrapper that decodes the binary data to text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from io import BytesIO, StringIO
from zipfile import ZipFile

response = requests.get(url)
zip_file = ZipFile(BytesIO(response.content))
files = zip_file.namelist()
with zip_file.open(files[0]) as csvfile:   
    print(pd.read_csv(csvfile, encoding='utf8', sep=","))
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Aran-Fey alluded to:

```
import zipfile
import csv
import io

with open('/path/to/archive.zip', 'r') as f:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(f) as zf:
        csv_filename = zf.namelist()[0]  # see namelist() for the list of files in the archive
        with zf.open(csv_filename) as csv_f:
            csv_f_as_text = io.TextIOWrapper(csv_f)
            reader = csv.reader(csv_f_as_text)
```

`csv.reader` (and `csv.DictReader`) require a file-like object opened in text mode. Normally this is not a problem when simply `open(...)`ing  file in `'r'` mode, as the Python 3 docs say, text mode is the default: "The default mode is 'r' (open for reading text, synonym of 'rt')". But if you try `rt` with `open` on a `ZipFile`, you'll see an error that: `ZipFile.open() requires mode "r" or "w"`:

```
        with zf.open(csv_filename, 'rt') as csv_f:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
...    
ValueError: open() requires mode "r" or "w"
```

That's what `io.TextIOWrapper` is for -- for wrapping byte streams to be readable as text, decoding them on the fly.