# How to open an unicode text file inside a zip?

Tags: python, file-io, python-3.x, unicode, zip

I tried

```
with zipfile.ZipFile("5.csv.zip", "r") as zfile:
    for name in zfile.namelist():
        with zfile.open(name, 'rU') as readFile:
                line = readFile.readline()
                print(line)
                split = line.split('\t')
```

it answers:

```
b'$0.0\t1822\t1\t1\t1\n'
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "zip.py", line 6
    split = line.split('\t')
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
```

How to open the text file as unicode instead of as `b`?

Comment: It looks to me like the zip library doesn't support encoding parameters for `open`. If that's correct I think you'll have to use the `codecs.EncodedFile` wrapper or manually decode each line.

Comment: Do you know the correct encoding for the file? It looks like utf-8 to me but it's a bad idea to guess if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*edit* For Python 3, using `io.TextIOWrapper` as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20603185/2337736) describes is the best choice. The answer below could still be helpful for 2.x. I don't think anything below is actually incorrect even for 3.x, but `io.TestIOWrapper` is still better.

If the file is utf-8, this will work:

```
# the rest of the code as above, then:
with zfile.open(name, 'rU') as readFile:
    line = readFile.readline().decode('utf8')
    # etc
```

If you're going to be iterating over the file you can use `codecs.iterdecode`, but that won't work with `readline()`.

```
with zfile.open(name, 'rU') as readFile:
    for line in codecs.iterdecode(readFile, 'utf8'):
        print line
        # etc
```

Note that neither approach is necessarily safe for multibyte encodings. For example, little-endian UTF-16 represents the newline character with the bytes `b'\x0A\x00'`. A non-unicode aware tool looking for newlines will split that incorrectly, leaving the null bytes on the following line. In such a case you'd have to use something that doesn't try to split the input by newlines, such as `ZipFile.read`, and then decode the whole byte string at once. This is not a concern for utf-8.

Comment: I've checked and indeed `.readline().decode('utf-16')` fails with an exception. Worse, `codecs.iterdecode()` produces wrong output silently (newlines are shifted to the next line). [`io.TextIOWrapper()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20603185/4279) avoids such problems.

Comment: I was told that Python 3 solved Unicode errors once and for all. What am I missing?

Comment: @oneloop - well, I don't know what you're missing, you haven't given any context. Python 3 makes it harder to accidentally mix encoded bytes and Unicode objects, which is a common cause of confusing errors in Python 2 because it apparently works until you hit data that actually causes implicit decoding/encoding with the default character encoding. But it's not magic, you still need to decode to turn binary data into characters or encode to do the reverse.

Answer (score 23):

To convert a byte stream into Unicode stream, you could use [`io.TextIOWrapper()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper):

```
encoding = 'utf-8'
with zipfile.ZipFile("5.csv.zip") as zfile:
    for name in zfile.namelist():
        with zfile.open(name) as readfile:
            for line in io.TextIOWrapper(readfile, encoding):
                print(repr(line))
```

Note: `TextIOWrapper()` uses universal newline mode by default. `rU` mode in `zfile.open()` is deprecated since version 3.4.

It avoids issues with multibyte encodings described in [@Peter DeGlopper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20602013/4279).

Comment: Yeah, if that works over filelike objects that's probably the safest answer in cases where you can't provide an encoding when opening the file (or use the `codecs.open` method.) I had seen the recommendation to use it in place of `rU` mode, but since 3.4 isn't out yet the deprecation warning didn't seem applicable. Proper handling of multibyte newlines is a compelling reason even without that, though - I wonder how much that had to do with the decision to deprecate?

Comment: It does work. It is *the way* to do it in Python 3. (sys.stdin, sys.stdout, (text) pipes in `subprocess` module are created using `TextIOWrapper`). `codecs.open` expect a filename (I don't see how it helps with the zipfile). `codecs.getreader(encoding)(file_obj)` might be useful on Python 2.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking in the general case - I don't see a better option for zipfiles. Perhaps my comment would be better worded "given that that works over filelike objects..."

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're seeing that error is because you are trying to mix bytes with unicode. The argument to `split` must also be byte-string:

```
>>> line = b'$0.0\t1822\t1\t1\t1\n'
>>> line.split(b'\t')
[b'$0.0', b'1822', b'1', b'1', b'1\n']
```

To get a unicode string, use [decode](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode):

```
>>> line.decode('utf-8')
'$0.0\t1822\t1\t1\t1\n'
```