# How to ignore invalid lines in a file?

Tags: python, file-io, python-3.x, utf-8

I'm iterating over a file

```
for line in io.TextIOWrapper(readFile, encoding = 'utf8'):
```

when the file contains the following line

```
b'"""\xea\x11"\t1664\t507\t137\t2\n'
```

that generates the following exception

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xea in position
>   3: invalid continuation byte

How can I make my script to ignore such lines and continue with the good ones?

Comment: As a side note, why are you using `io.TextIOWrapper(readFile, …)` explicitly, instead of just `open`/`io.open`-ing the file in text mode in the first place? There are occasionally good reasons to do this, but I've seen people doing it for no good reason…

Comment: @abarnert the reason is explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601796/how-to-open-an-unicode-text-file-inside-a-zip/20603185?noredirect=1#20603185

Comment: OK, cool. Meanwhile… why do you want to skip over lines like this? It seems like in an arbitrary file that's got embedded garbage, the chances that the garbage is nicely separated out by lines are pretty slim, so half the time you're going to end up skipping over some non-terminate garbage plus a real line of text. Also, a lot of things are valid UTF-8 but complete nonsense. If you know what the actual format is, it would be a lot better to parse it correctly than to use this heuristic.

Comment: The file is not garbage, it's http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/googlebooks-eng-1M-1gram-20090715-8.csv.zip

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you actually want to ignore the whole line if it has any invalid characters, you will have to *know* there were invalid characters. Which means you can't use `TextIOWrapper`, and have to instead decode the lines manually. What you want to do is this:

```
for bline in readFile:
    try:
        line = bline.decode('utf-8')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        continue
    # do stuff with line
```

However, note that this does not give you the same newline behavior as using a text file; if you need that, you'll need to be explicit about that as well.

Answer (score 7):

Pass the `errors='ignore'` argument to `TextIOWrapper`. There are other options available as specified [here](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/io.html).

Comment: The problem is that this skips over invalid characters silently, so it doesn't give you any way to ignore the whole line (or even know which one you want to ignore).

Answer (score 4):

I think you can pass the `errors` parameter:

```
io.TextIOWrapper(readfile, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')
```