# Iterdecode skipping lines from file

Tags: python, python-3.x

When reading a .txt file from a zip and using iterdecode to read line by line, the itercode is skipping not empty odd lines.

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('path/file.zip', 'r') as zipobj:
    for current_file in zipobj.namelist():
        file = zipobj.open(current_file)
        for line in codecs.iterdecode(file, 'latin-1'): #Latin-1 for accents
            print(line)
```

My files are .txt files and for each file:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5, etc.

print(line) gives:

line 1
line 3
line 5, etc.
```

Before I was using file.open (without iterdecodes) and it worked fine, but I need to read from .zip.

Thanks.

Comment: `file = zipobj.open(current_file)` did you mean? `current` is not defined here

Comment: Yes, thanks. I edited the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by using one of the answers from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601796/how-to-open-an-unicode-text-file-inside-a-zip/20603185#20603185). I will post here the solution as well as it's not so evident in the other post (not the accepted solution anyway).

```
import io
with zipfile.ZipFile('path/file.zip', 'r') as zipobj:
    for name in zipobj.namelist():
        with zipobj.open(name) as readfile:
            for line in io.TextIOWrapper(readfile, 'latin-1'):
                print(line)
```

Now all lines are correctly printed.