# _csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Tags: python, csv

At the start of my csv program:

```
import csv     # imports the csv module
import sys      # imports the sys module

f = open('Address Book.csv', 'rb') # opens the csv file
try:
    reader = csv.reader(f)  # creates the reader object
    for row in reader:   # iterates the rows of the file in orders
        print (row)    # prints each row
finally:
    f.close()      # closing
```

And the error is:

```
    for row in reader:   # iterates the rows of the file in orders
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of this (and the rest):

```
f = open('Address Book.csv', 'rb')
```

Do this:

```
with open('Address Book.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f) 
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

The context manager means you don't need the `finally: f.close()`, because it will automatically close the file on an error, or on exiting the context.

Comment: will this work for Python 3 version

Comment: @anj yes, yes it will.

Answer (score 2):

The solution in this (duplicate?) question [csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515053/csv-error-iterator-should-return-strings-not-bytes) helped me:

```
f = open('Address Book.csv', "rt")
```

or

```
with open('Address Book.csv', "rt") as f:
```

or (using gzip)

```
import gzip
f = gzip.open('Address Book.csv', "rt")
```

or

```
import gzip
gzip.open('Address Book.csv', "rt") as f:
```