# How to update rows in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

Hello I'm trying to make a program that updates the values in a csv. The user searches for the ID, and if the ID exists, it gets the new values you want to replace on the row where that ID number is. Here `row[0:9]` is the length of my ID.

My idea was to scan each row from 0-9 or where my ID number is, and when its found, I will replace the values besides it using the `.replace()` method. This how i did it:

```
    def update_thing():
        replace = stud_ID +','+ stud_name +','+ stud_course +','+ stud_year
        empty = []
        with open(fileName, 'r+') as upFile:
            for row in f:
                if row[0:9] == stud_ID:
                    row=row.replace(row,replace)
                    msg = Label(upd_win, text="Updated Successful", font="fixedsys 12 bold").place(x=3,y=120)
                if not row[0:9] == getID:
                    empty.append(row)

        upFile.close()
        upFile = open(fileName, 'w')
        upFile.writelines(empty)
        upFile.close()
```

But it's not working, I need ideas on how to get through this.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you provide a snip of your CSV data? Also, do you have pandas?

Comment: Don't try to do this manually.  Instead, use the Python CSV package, `csv`.  It will both decode and encode rows of a CSV file, handling all of the escapes automatically.

Comment: @COLDSPEED sir I added the image.

Comment: @TomKarzes Sir, I already imported the csv package. And thats why row[] is working. But I think I have the wrong implementation I guess?

Comment: The CSV package handles rows as lists, not comma-separated strings.  You're trying to use a string with explicit commas.  Don't do that.

Comment: Some of my other functions are working, I have an ADD and DELETE. But this one is complicated.

Comment: @TomKarzes so it reads it like that huh.. thanks sir, I'll try doing it. Might work

Comment: Remove the string operations.  Remove all hard-coded `','` strings.  Use lists.  I don't know how much more clearly I can say this.

Comment: Also, you're not using the `csv` package at all here.  Just because you import it doesn't mean all of Python's I/O will automatically change to use it.  You need to be using `csv.reader` and `csv.writer`, and the `writerows` method of your write object.  Try just reading and writing a CSV file first, before trying to make changes to it.

Comment: @TomKarzes sir i tried this: '       Swriter.writerow([empty])'
       'Swriter.writerow([replace])' empties it and replaced.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

With the `csv` module you can iterate over the rows and access each one as a dict. As also noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16020923/6085135), the preferred way to update a file is by using temporary file.

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import shutil
import csv

filename = 'my.csv'
tempfile = NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', delete=False)

fields = ['ID', 'Name', 'Course', 'Year']

with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile, tempfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=fields)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(tempfile, fieldnames=fields)
    for row in reader:
        if row['ID'] == str(stud_ID):
            print('updating row', row['ID'])
            row['Name'], row['Course'], row['Year'] = stud_name, stud_course, stud_year
        row = {'ID': row['ID'], 'Name': row['Name'], 'Course': row['Course'], 'Year': row['Year']}
        writer.writerow(row)

shutil.move(tempfile.name, filename)
```

If that's still not working you might try one of these encodings:

```
with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8') as csvfile, tempfile:
with open(filename, 'r', encoding='ascii') as csvfile, tempfile:
```

Edit: added str, print and encodings

Comment: thanks sir, your code works as it doesn't get the message of failed. but still it doesn't get replaced.

Comment: I made my code work by using r+b, but still your code is better as its using the package. But still, like mine, it doesn't get changed

Comment: The rb vs r is a Python 2 vs 3 issue I believe. Maybe you need to convert stud_ID to a string? str(stud_ID)

Comment: hello sir, 'stud_ID = str(ID_num.get())' this was actually stud_ID do i convert it again?

Comment: Once is enough. I'll retry this in Python 2

Comment: So rb is not correct https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132034/csv-error-iterator-should-return-strings-not-bytes-did-you-open-the-file-in

Comment: I also added a print so if we can see if the conditional is working

Comment: how would we be doing this if we import pandas? yes still not working sir. Anyway thanks. I think I should use pandas on this. its not looking so good.

Comment: `pandas.read_csv`  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: What would be the point of using ASCII in this case? Doesn't UTF-8 support a much wider  char set?

Answer (score 1):

Simply write to a new file at same time reading over the lines of original, conditionally changing the row based on *Stud_ID* value. New file is suffixed *_new* in name.

```
line_replace = stud_ID +','+ stud_name +','+ stud_course +','+ stud_year

with open(fileName, 'r') as readFile, open(fileName.replace('.csv', '_new.csv'), 'w') as writeFile: 
   for row in readFile:
      if row[0:9] == stud_ID:
         writeFile.write(line_replace)
         msg = Label(upd_win, text="Updated Successful", font="fixedsys 12 bold").place(x=3,y=120)
      else: 
         writeFile.write(row)
```

Comment: hello sir, your code deletes everything. Does the .csv and _new.csv gets automatically created here?

Comment: Very strange. Files are deleted or content in files are deleted? No file system handling is occurring here. No file or content should be deleted from this code and *_new* should be created. I just tested. Maybe other code does that deletion. Are you using Python 3?