# Replacing a row in csv file using Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, csv, overwrite

I have a question whose variations have already been asked, but I'm not able to find an answer among all previous posts to my particular question. So I hope someone can help me ...

I have a csv file as such (in this example, there are a total of 18 rows, and 4 columns, with the first 2 rows containing headers).

"Employees.csv" 17
ID  Name    Value   Location
25-2002 James   1.2919  Finance
25-2017 Matthew 2.359   Legal
30-3444 Rob 3.1937  Operations
55-8988 Fred    3.1815  Research
26-1000 Lisa    4.3332  Research
56-0909 John    3.3533  Legal
45-8122 Anna    3.8887  Finance
10-1000 Rachel  4.1448  Maintenance
30-9000 Frank   3.7821  Maintenance
25-3000 Angela  5.5854  Service
45-4321 Christopher 9.1598  Legal
44-9821 Maddie  8.5823  Service
20-4000 Ruth    7.47    Operations
50-3233 Vera    5.5092  Operations
65-2045 Sydney  3.4542  Executive
45-8720 Vladimir    0.2159  Finance

I'd like to round the values in the 3rd column to 2 decimals, i.e., round(value, 2). So basically, I want to open the file, read column #3 (minus first 2 rows), round each value, write them back, and save the file. After reading through other similar posts, I've now learned that it's best to *always* create a temp file to do this work instead of trying to change the same file at once.  So I have the following code:

```
import csv, os
val = []

with open('path/Employees.csv', 'r') as rf, open('path/tmpf.csv, 'w') as tmpf:
    reader = csv.reader(rf)
    writer = csv.writer(tmpf)
    for _ in range(2): #skip first 2 rows
        next(reader)
    for line in reader:
        val.append(float(line[2]))  # read 3 column into list 'val'

#    [... this is where i got stuck!  
#     ... how do I round each value of val, and
#     ... write everything back to the tmpf file ?]

os.remove('path/Employees.csv')
os.rename('path/tmpf', 'path/Employees.csv')
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update rows in a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46126082/how-to-update-rows-in-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 0):

You could

```
rounded_val = [ round (v,2) for v in val ]
```

to generate the list of rounded values.