# Python: Trying to search through csv first column and spliting it if len > 30 in another file on the same row

Tags: python, csv

The title isn't big enough for me to explain this so here it goes:

I have a csv file looking something like this:

Example csv containing

```
long string with some special characters , number, string, number
long string with some special characters , number, string, number
long string with some special characters , number, string, number
long string with some special characters , number, string, number
```

I want to go through the first column and if the length of the string is greater then 20 do this:

LINE 20 :   long string with som, e special characters

split the string, modify first csv with first part of the string, and create a new csv and add the other part on the same line number, leaving the rest just whitespace

---

what i have for now is this:
this below doesn't do anything right now, its just what I made to try and explain to myself and figure out how could i do new file writing with splitString

```
fileName = file name 
maxCollumnLength = number of rows in the whole set 
lineNum = line number of a string that is greater then 20  
splitString = second part of the split string that should be written on another file


def newopenfile(fileName, maxCollumnLength, lineNum, splitString):
    with open(fileName, 'rw', encoding="utf8") as nf:
        writer = csv.writer(fileName, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        for i in range(0, maxCollumnLength-1):
            #write whitespace until reaching lineNum of a string thats bigger then 20 then write that part of the string to a csv
```

this goes through the first column and checks the length

```
fileName = 'uskrs.csv'
firstColList=[]         #an empty list to store the second column
splitString=[]
i = 0
with open(fileName, 'rw', encoding="utf8") as rf:
    reader = csv.reader(rf, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        if len(row[0]) > 20:
            i+=1
            #split row and parse the other end of the row to newopenfile(fileName, len(reader), i, splitString )
            #print(row[0])
        #for debuging    
        firstColList.append(row[0])
```

from this point i am stuck at how to actualy change the string in the csv and how to split them

THE STRING COULD ALSO HAVE 60+ chars, so it would need splitting more then 2 times and storing it in more then 2 csvs

I suck at explaining the problem, so if you have any questions please do ask

Okay so i was sucessful in dividing the first column if it has length greater then 20, and replace the first column with first 20 chars

```
import csv

def checkLength(column, readFile, writeFile, maxLen):
    counter = 0
    i = 0
    idxSplitItems = []
    final = []
    newSplits = 0
    with open(readFile,'r', encoding="utf8", newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        your_list = list(reader)
        final = your_list
        for sublist in your_list:
            #del sublist[-1]    -remove last invisible element
            i+=1
            data = removeUnwanted(sublist[column])
            print(data)
            if len(data) > maxLen:
                counter += 1 # Number of large
                idxSplitItems.append(split_bylen(i,data,maxLen))
                if len(idxSplitItems) > newSplits: newSplits = len(idxSplitItems)
                final[i-1][column] = split_bylen(i,data,maxLen)[1]
                final[i-1][column] = removeUnwanted(final[i-1][column])
            print("After split data: "+ data)
            print("After split final: "+ final[i-1][column])   

    writeSplitToCSV(writeFile, final)
    checkCols(final, 6)
    return final, idxSplitItems
def removeUnwanted(data):
    data = data.replace(',',' ')
    return data

def split_bylen(index, item, maxLen):
    clean = removeUnwanted(item)
    splitList = [clean[ind:ind+maxLen] for ind in range(0, len(item), maxLen)]
    splitList.insert(0,index)
    return splitList

def writeSplitToCSV(writeFile,data):
    with open(writeFile,'w', encoding="utf8", newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(data)

def checkCols(data, columns):
    for sublist in data:
        if len(sublist)-1!=columns:
            print ("[X] This row doesnt have the same amount of columns as others: "+sublist)
        else:
            print("All okay")
#len(data) #how many split items
#print(your_list[0][0])
#print("Number of large: ", counter)

final, idxSplitItems = checkLength(0,'test.csv','final.csv', 30)
print("------------------------")
print(idxSplitItems)
print("-------------------------")
print(final)
```

Now I have a problem with this part of the code, notice this:

```
print("After split data: "+ data)
print("After split final: "+ final[i-1][column])
```

This is to check if removing comma worked.

with example of

> "BUTKOVIĆ VESNA , DIPL.IUR."

data returns

> BUTKOVIĆ VESNA    DIPL.IUR.

but final returns

> BUTKOVIĆ VESNA , DIPL.IUR.

why does my final return "," again but in data its gone, must be something done in "split_bylen()" that makes it do that

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are fun!

To overwrite the original csv see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46126082/how-to-update-rows-in-a-csv-file). You would have to use Dictreader & Dictwriter. I keep your method of reading just for clarity.

```
writecsvs = {} #store each line of each new csv 
# e.g. {'csv1':[[row0_split1,row0_num,row0_str,row0_num],[row1_split1,row1_num,row1_str,row1_num],...],
#       'csv2':[[row0_split2,row0_num,row0_str,row0_num],[row1_split2,row1_num,row1_str,row1_num],...],
#       .
#       .
#       .}

with open(fileName, mode='rw', encoding="utf-8-sig") as rf:
    reader = csv.reader(rf, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:            
        col1 = row[0]
        # check size & split
        # decide number of new csvs
        # overwrite original csv
        # store new content in writecsvs dict

for # Loop over each csv in writecsvs:
    writelines = # Get List of Lines
    out_file = open('csv1.csv', mode='w') # use the keys in writecsvs for filenames
    for line in writelines:
        out_file.write(line)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried hard and I got to a solution I can work with....
I made :

1. I can search csv first column for strings longer then 30chars
2. I can split the long string for every 30chars and store them in a list
3. I can write a new csv with correct information with shorter string

PROBLEM:
It doesnt remove "," inside of a string (not the one needed for a csv), but I made a function to remove commas if they exist