# How can I get python to compare scraped data to a populated csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a python code that creates a csv file and populates it with the names of current U.S. state supreme court justices. I am have gotten python to scrape for data, and to create a csv and populate it with the data.

I am trying to get python to run daily (I have set up windows task scheduler), scrape the same pages, compare the new data to the old csv, alert the user whether or not the scraped data is equivalent to the data in the csv, track the changes, and to update the csv with the newly scraped data.

I'm new to python, so this I am unsure as to how to proceed with my code.

What can I add to my code to make this happen? Thank you! Here is my current code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

list = ['https://ballotpedia.org/Alabama_Supreme_Court', 
'https://ballotpedia.org/Alaska_Supreme_Court', 
'https://ballotpedia.org/Arizona_Supreme_Court', 
'https://ballotpedia.org/Arkansas_Supreme_Court', 
'https://ballotpedia.org/California_Supreme_Court', 
'https://ballotpedia.org/Colorado_Supreme_Court', 
'https://ballotpedia.org/Connecticut_Supreme_Court', 
'https://ballotpedia.org/Delaware_Supreme_Court']

temp_dict = {}

for page in list:
    r = requests.get(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    temp_dict[page.split('/')[-1]] = [item.text for item in 
    soup.select("table.wikitable.sortable.jquery- 
    tablesorter a")]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(temp_dict, 
orient='index').transpose()
df.to_csv('State Supreme Court Justices.csv')
```

Comment: have you just deleted the previous question and created it again?

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46126082/how-to-update-rows-in-a-csv-file) explains how a CSV can be updated using a `NamedTemporaryFile`, also do check this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html) for comparing two pandas data-frames:

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is, see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your problem. Let me give you an example.

```
from simplified_scrapy import Spider, SimplifiedDoc, SimplifiedMain
from datetime import datetime
import requests
class MySpider(Spider):
  name = 'ballotpedia.org'
  allowed_domains = ['ballotpedia.org']
  start_urls = [
    'https://ballotpedia.org/Alabama_Supreme_Court', 
    'https://ballotpedia.org/Alaska_Supreme_Court', 
    'https://ballotpedia.org/Arizona_Supreme_Court', 
    'https://ballotpedia.org/Arkansas_Supreme_Court', 
    'https://ballotpedia.org/California_Supreme_Court', 
    'https://ballotpedia.org/Colorado_Supreme_Court', 
    'https://ballotpedia.org/Connecticut_Supreme_Court', 
    'https://ballotpedia.org/Delaware_Supreme_Court'
  ]
  # refresh_urls = True # For debug. If efresh_urls = True, start_urls will be crawled again.
  custom_down = True # All pages are downloaded using custom methods
  def customDown(self,url):
    if url["url"] not in self.start_urls: return ""
    r = requests.get(url['url']) # Use requests to download the page and return the HTML string
    return r.content.decode('utf-8')

  def extract(self, url, html, models, modelNames):
    if url["url"] not in self.start_urls: return True
    doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
    lstA = doc.select('table.wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter').listA(url=url["url"]) # Get link data for subsequent crawling
    return {"Urls": lstA, "Data": lstA} # Return data to framework
  # If you want to collect start_urls regularly, override this method.
  # It returns an array of hours and minutes
  def plan(self):
    if datetime.now().weekday()>=6: # Except for weekends
      return []
    else:
      return [{'hour':8,'minute':30},{'hour':18,'minute':0}]

SimplifiedMain.startThread(MySpider()) # Start crawling
```