# simple way to print out each cell in csv python

Tags: python, csv

i have got some set of csv i auto generate and i need advise on the following:

1. i have three labels on the csv  ( Serial Number, Starting Code, Key) see the image below

[image]

2. from the image above i create `input("")` to check if the input keyword is equal to any of the column, if the input is equal to any of the column then print the rest of the cells in the row e.g if

```
if input == 'KB57000001003', print ('983901181',    'f3e78b3163de11f1dc143082205262e9')
```

and stored
them in variable `x` and `y`  (`x = '983901181'` and `y = 'f3e78b3163de11f1dc143082205262e9'`)

I have try to do this with csv built in functions but can't. See my code below:

```
 import csv
dict = []
file = 'token.csv'

search = input("Search Serial number here")
inValue = 0
with open(file, 'r') as my_file:
    reader = csv.reader(my_file)
    for row in reader:
        

        ## this is for serial number
        for i in range(len(row)):
            #dict.append(i)
            
            if i == 0:
                print(f'The row number {i} is  {row[i]}')
                dict.append(row[i])
                if row[i]== search:
                      inValue = row[i]
                      print(f" Congratulation ! your input is {search} and match with {search} in ")               
            elif i > 0:
                continue
            elif i == len(row):
                break
        for i in range(len(row)):
            if i >=1:
                dict_1.append(row[i])
            elif i == len(row):
                break


              
          
print('\n')
print(inValue)
print('\n')
print(dict)   

Out:
Search Serial number here: KB57000001006
The row number 0 is  Serial Number
The row number 0 is  KB57000001001
The row number 0 is  KB57000001002
The row number 0 is  KB57000001003
The row number 0 is  KB57000001004
The row number 0 is  KB57000001005
The row number 0 is  KB57000001006
 Congratulation ! your input is KB57000001006 and match with KB57000001006 in 


KB57000001006

 the list in first Column is ['Serial Number', 'KB57000001001', 'KB57000001002', 'KB57000001003', 'KB57000001004', 'KB57000001005', 'KB57000001006']
```

3. i was only able to scan through the column and get the match but can't print the next two rows in the column, please can you help
   Thanks Greatly in advance

Comment: maybe it would be simpler if you would use `pandas.DataFrame` instead of module `csv` and standard lists.

Comment: next two rows `row[i+1:i+3]`

Comment: `csv` is for reading and writing - in rest you use standard functions for lists

Comment: If `i` have value for `range(len(row))` then you don't need to check `elif i == len(row):                 break` - because `i` will be always smaller then `len(row)` - range gives values `0...len(row)-1`. And I don't understand why you use `i == 0` and `elif i > 0: continue` - this way you check only first row. If you want to check for all rows then you don't need `if/elif/else`

Comment: to print next two rows you should rather first read all rows and later work with list of rows.

Comment: @furas Thanks greatly I will try this also and feed you back. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood from your problem is you want to search for a value from the CSV column name "serial number"  and print the next rows of the corresponding serial number. Please correct me if I have misunderstood anything.

here is a demo code for this:

```
import csv

out_list = []
output_dict = {}
file = 'new.csv'

search = input("Search Serial number here: ")
with open(file, 'r') as my_file:
    reader = csv.reader(my_file)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == search:
            print(f"Congratulation ! your input is {search} and match with {search}")
            out_list = [row[0], row[1], row[2]]
            output_dict = {"serial_number": row[0], "starting_code": row[1], "key": row[2]}


print(f"your input list values {out_list}\n")
print(f"your matching dictionary {output_dict}")
```

the output will be like this:

```
Search Serial number here: KB57000001006
Congratulation ! your input is KB57000001006 and match with KB57000001006 in 
your input list values ['KB57000001006', '22442', 'dfdfdf']

your matching dictionary {'serial_number': 'KB57000001006', 'starting_code': '22442', 'key': 'dfdfdf'}
```

Comment: Thanks greatly !  You very right. This give me head up. I will try this and run my entire code together and I will feed you back. Thanks Again !!

Comment: Hi @Raisul, This solve the issues but, i couldn't store and update the count count row. please check the url here [link] https://i.postimg.cc/9XxfQJ36/New-update-count.png[/link]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46126082/how-to-update-rows-in-a-csv-file
check this link @AyobamiAkinlolu-ojo

Comment: Thanks greatly will check it out @Raisul