# Why codecs.iterdecode() eats empty strings?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8, codec

Why the following two decoding methods return different results?

```
>>> import codecs
>>>
>>> data = ['', '', 'a', '']
>>> list(codecs.iterdecode(data, 'utf-8'))
[u'a']
>>> [codecs.decode(i, 'utf-8') for i in data]
[u'', u'', u'a', u'']
```

Is this a bug or expected behavior? My Python version 2.7.13.

Comment: It seems it's checking whether the decoder managed to return a value but this also discards empty strings: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/codecs.py#l1040

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is normal. `iterdecode` takes an iterator over encoded chunks and returns an iterator over decoded chunks, but it doesn't promise a one-to-one correspondence. All it guarantees is that the concatenation of all output chunks is a valid decoding of the concatenation of all input chunks.

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/codecs.py#L1029), you'll see it's explicitly discarding empty output chunks:

```
def iterdecode(iterator, encoding, errors='strict', **kwargs):
    """
    Decoding iterator.
    Decodes the input strings from the iterator using an IncrementalDecoder.
    errors and kwargs are passed through to the IncrementalDecoder
    constructor.
    """
    decoder = getincrementaldecoder(encoding)(errors, **kwargs)
    for input in iterator:
        output = decoder.decode(input)
        if output:
            yield output
    output = decoder.decode("", True)
    if output:
        yield output
```

---

Be aware that the reason `iterdecode` exists, and the reason you wouldn't just call `decode` on all the chunks yourself, is that the decoding process is stateful. The UTF-8 encoded form of one character might be split over multiple chunks. Other codecs might have really weird stateful behavior, like maybe a byte sequence that inverts the case of all characters until you see that byte sequence again.