# Django: Read uploaded CSV file using FileField instance

Tags: python, django, csv

I'm trying to read the data of a .csv file uploaded by a user in a field of type `FileField`. I have no problem acessing the object, but I can't seem to make it work with the `csv` module. Here is what I'm trying:

```
reader = csv.reader(object.uploaded_file.read())
for rows in reader:
...
```

Where `object` is an instance of my model and `uploaded_file` the corresponding field.

**I'm getting this error:**

> iterator should return strings, not int (did you open the file in text
>   mode?)

Also,

I tried to use the `open()` method but whitout success. The documentation on this subject seems so vague. Even worst, the only thing I could find on the `read()` method used above is this:

> In addition to the listed methods, File exposes the following
>   attributes and methods of its file object: encoding, fileno, flush,
>   isatty, newlines, read, readinto, readline, readlines, seek,
>   softspace, tell, truncate, write, writelines, xreadlines, readable(),
>   writable(), and seekable().

**EDIT**

I know it probably has to do with the reading mode has this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515053/csv-error-iterator-should-return-strings-not-bytes) suggest, but how can I change the mode in this case ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's my workaround (as you shouldn't need to 'open' an already opened file in the case of a FileField upload).

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

def parse_file(self, csv_upload):
    file = csv_upload.read().decode('utf-8')
    csv_data = csv.reader(StringIO(file), delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_data:
        print(row)
```

Answer (score 3):

I finally found a work around:

```
 reader = csv.reader(open(object.uploaded_file.path,'r'))
```

Instead of using built-in `read()` or `open()` of `File` object which has low documentation as I said in my question, I used the `path` attribute.