# Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes

Tags: python-3.x, csv

My code is throwing this error:

```
    File "testdata.py", line 35, in <module>
      for row in reader:
    File "C:\Python36\lib\csv.py", line 111, in __next__
      self.fieldnames
    File "C:\Python36\lib\csv.py", line 98, in fieldnames
     self._fieldnames = next(self.reader)
    _csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the 
    file in text mode?)
```

---

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pOJ1KNTlpzE) and did all that has been done on the video several times and look for similar problems here, but so far I haven't found a way to solve my issue.

[These are the files used in the video](https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/30-Days-of-Python/tree/master/Day%2016/hungrypy).

This error is not similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515053/csv-error-iterator-should-return-strings-not-bytes), I tried using that fix however it lead me to another error.

My code:

```
filename = "data.csv"
temp_file = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
with open(filename, "rb") as csvfile, temp_file:
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
     fieldnames = ['id', 'name', 'email', 'amount', 'sent']
     writer = csv.DictWriter(temp_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
     #writer.writeheader()
     for row in reader:
         print(row)
         writer.writerow({
                "id": row["id"],
                "name": row["name"],
                "email": row["email"],
                "amount": "1293.33",
                "sent": "",
              })
```

Comment: You've opened the file as "rb" - just use "r"...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515053/csv-error-iterator-should-return-strings-not-bytes)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515053/csv-error-iterator-should-return-strings-not-bytes

Comment: Paste "Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes" into Google and you'll get **many** examples of how to solve this problem. Trace messages that can be easily copied and pasted are one of the reasons Python is so friendly to new developers.

Comment: i tried that fix but it didnt work out. it lead me to another error

Comment: Then open a new question telling us what that new error is. Do you really think code you write will only have one error. It is likely to have layers and layers and layers of errors that you expose and fix one by one.

Comment: I don't think it will have layers of errors since I'm following a video tutorial. It is not a code i built myself but a code I follow on the video which is already been made.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

filename = "data.csv"
temp_file = NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', delete=False)
with open(filename, "r", newline='') as csvfile, temp_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    fieldnames = ['id', 'name', 'email', 'amount', 'sent']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(temp_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    #writer.writeheader()
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        writer.writerow({
                "id": row["id"],
                "name": row["name"],
                "email": row["email"],
                "amount": "1293.33",
                "sent": "",
            })
```

- Set `mode='w'` for `NamedTemporaryFile`.
- Set `mode='r'` for `open` to read.
- Set `newline=''` for `open` to read.

Implement these changes and it works in my testing with Python 3.6.0.