# How to fill QTable from CSV file

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer

This code won't work on mine, No happen whenever I clicked the buttons.Please help. this is the code below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import csv

import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 2)
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, fileName, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.fileName = fileName

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)

        self.tableView = QtGui.QTableView(self)
        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

        self.pushButtonLoad = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButtonLoad.setText("Load Csv File!")
        self.pushButtonLoad.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonLoad_clicked)

        self.pushButtonWrite = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButtonWrite.setText("Write Csv File!")
        self.pushButtonWrite.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonWrite_clicked)

        self.layoutVertical = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.tableView)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.pushButtonLoad)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.pushButtonWrite)

    def loadCsv(self, fileName):
        with open(fileName, "rb") as fileInput:
            for row in csv.reader(fileInput):    
                items = [
                    QtGui.QStandardItem(field)
                    for field in row
                ]
                self.model.appendRow(items)

    def writeCsv(self, fileName):
        with open(fileName, "wb") as fileOutput:
            writer = csv.writer(fileOutput)
            for rowNumber in range(self.model.rowCount()):
                fields = [
                    self.model.data(
                        self.model.index(rowNumber, columnNumber),
                        QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole
                    )
                    for columnNumber in range(self.model.columnCount())
                ]
                writer.writerow(fields)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButtonWrite_clicked(self):
        self.writeCsv(self.fileName)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButtonLoad_clicked(self):
        self.loadCsv(self.fileName)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow("C:/PythonPrograms/sample.csv")
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Change `open(fileName, "rb")` to `open(fileName, "r")` and `open(fileName, "wb")` to `open(fileName, "w")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515053/csv-error-iterator-should-return-strings-not-bytes)

Comment: The example code works fine for me using python-2.7. What do you mean by: "it won't work"? What exactly happens? Do you see error messages? Have you checked the csv file to make sure it is not an empty file?

Comment: thank you for the responses :) The error shows: _csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Comment: thankss @eyllanesc, it works!