# How to print a csv content from remote url using python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, urllib3

I want to print csv content from remote url, but I get this:

> Error                                     Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 for row in cr:
>         2     print(row)
>
> Error: iterator should return strings, not int (did you open the file
>   in text mode?)

My code is:

```
import csv
import urllib3

medals_url = "http://winterolympicsmedals.com/medals.csv"
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request("GET", medals_url)
r.status
response = r.data
cr = csv.reader(response)
for row in cr:
    print(row)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515053/csv-error-iterator-should-return-strings-not-bytes)

Comment: try changing `cr = csv.reader(response)` to `cr = csv.reader(response.decode('utf-8'))`, note: this is assuming the byte stream is utf-8 encoded.

Comment: I would have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400867/pandas-read-csv-from-url this will put your data in a useful structure, so you can do something with it

Comment: @MathewSavage You are right! Thank you so much!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done directly with Pandas, which will put your data in a useful format for processing

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('http://winterolympicsmedals.com/medals.csv')
```

Answer (score 3):

This might help.

```
import urllib3

medals_url = "http://winterolympicsmedals.com/medals.csv"
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request("GET", medals_url)
r.status

data = "".join(map(chr,r.data))
print(data)
data = data.split('\n')
for row in data:
    print(row) # or print(row.split(','))
```