# CSV Error About Strings and Bytes Still Not Working

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I keep running into an error and it really seems like I should have debugged it from what I've read online. I am trying to append rows from one CSV to another.

This is the error:

```
for row in reader:
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

Below is my code. I've tried slight variations of these, like "rt" instead of "r".

```
import csv

#tried this first
with open('input.csv') as myfile:
    reader = csv.reader(myfile)
    writer = csv.writer(open('output.csv', 'a'))
    for row in reader:
        if "EMAIL" or "EMAIL ADDRESS" or "Email" in row:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Tried this second

```
reader = csv.reader(open('input.csv', 'r', encoding="utf-8"))
writer = csv.writer(open('output.csv', 'a'))
for row in reader:
    if "EMAIL" or "EMAIL ADDRESS" or "Email" in row:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Tried this last

```
reader = csv.reader(open('input.csv', 'r', encoding="ascii"))
writer = csv.writer(open('output.csv', 'a'))
for row in reader:
    if "EMAIL" or "EMAIL ADDRESS" or "Email" in row:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Help would be super appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515053/csv-error-iterator-should-return-strings-not-bytes)

Comment: @Primusa I've been following those answers as you can tell by what I've been trying and it hasn't been working.

Comment: The same error happens each time?

Comment: `if "EMAIL" or "EMAIL ADDRESS" or "Email" in row` is incorrect. Must be `if "EMAIL" in row or "EMAIL ADDRESS" in row or "Email" in row`. An even better solution is `if "email" in row.lower()`. This remark probably is not related to your question, but does address the correctness of your program.

Comment: Pls disregard the part about `row.lower()` in my previous comment, as it is incorrect.

Comment: None of the code blocks you show should give the error you describe, as `open` with mode `'r'` should open the file in text mode. Are you sure you're actually running the code you're showing us, rather than some older version where you opened with mode `'rb'`?

Comment: @Blckknght you're right! I had moved the file and was saving the new files in the old location. Thank you!