# How to read a Google Contacts csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, google-contacts-api

I exported my Google Contacts into a CSV file and I am trying to parse it with `csv`:

```
import csv
contacts = csv.DictReader(open('google.csv', 'rb'))
for c in contacts:
    print(c)
```

This crashes with `csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)`

Following the hint:

```
import csv
contacts = csv.DictReader(open('google.csv', 'r'))
for c in contacts:
    print(c)
```

now crashes with `_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte`.

When looking at the details of the file, it indeeds looks weird, in the sense that `NULL` is interlaced with normal signs:

```
00000000  ff fe 4e 00 61 00 6d 00  65 00 2c 00 47 00 69 00  |..N.a.m.e.,.G.i.|
00000010  76 00 65 00 6e 00 20 00  4e 00 61 00 6d 00 65 00  |v.e.n. .N.a.m.e.|
00000020  2c 00 41 00 64 00 64 00  69 00 74 00 69 00 6f 00  |,.A.d.d.i.t.i.o.|
00000030  6e 00 61 00 6c 00 20 00  4e 00 61 00 6d 00 65 00  |n.a.l. .N.a.m.e.|
00000040  2c 00 46 00 61 00 6d 00  69 00 6c 00 79 00 20 00  |,.F.a.m.i.l.y. .|
00000050  4e 00 61 00 6d 00 65 00  2c 00 59 00 6f 00 6d 00  |N.a.m.e.,.Y.o.m.|
00000060  69 00 20 00 4e 00 61 00  6d 00 65 00 2c 00 47 00  |i. .N.a.m.e.,.G.|
00000070  69 00 76 00 65 00 6e 00  20 00 4e 00 61 00 6d 00  |i.v.e.n. .N.a.m.|
```

**Is this a normal thing with CSV files? And more importantly, is there a standard way to read them in and write them out (keeping that standard)?**

Answer (score 0):

You can try it using Pandas library that is the way that I used to read csv files.

```
import pandas as pd

contacts = pd.read_csv('google.csv', na_values=['NA'])
```

Also I have found this [link](https://realpython.com/python-csv/) that maybe can help you more.

Comment: Thanks - but have you actually parsed **Google Contacts** csv files? I get the same kind of error (impossible to decode the first `0xff`). Please not that the hex dump shows that this is not a normal text.

Comment: No, I have not parsed Google contacts before, I have found also this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515053/csv-error-iterator-should-return-strings-not-bytes) maybe there is a problem with the encoding.

Comment: No, this is more than that - all the letters are interleaved with a `0xff` - some kind of weird format