# How to convert csv to json with python on amazon lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function which attempts to take a csv file which was uploaded on a bucket, convert it to json and save it on another bucket.  Here is my code:

```
import json
import os
import boto3
import csv

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        file_key = record['s3']['object']['key']
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        csvfile = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=file_key)
        csvcontent = csvfile['Body'].read().split(b'\n')

        data = []
        csv_file = csv.DictReader(csvcontent)
        print(csv_file)
        data = list(csv_file)

        os.chdir('/tmp')
        JSON_PATH = file_key[6:] + ".json"
        print(data)
        with open(JSON_PATH, 'w') as output:
          json.dump(data, output)
          bucket_name = 'xxx'
          s3.upload_file(JSON_PATH, bucket_name, JSON_PATH)
```

The problem is that although when I test this locally on my machine the file can be converted to json, when I run the lambda function I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 19, in lambda_handler
    data = list(csv_file)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/csv.py", line 111, in __next__
    self.fieldnames
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/csv.py", line 98, in fieldnames
    self._fieldnames = next(self.reader)
```

Can someone help me understand why this happens? I have been trying a solution since a while and I don’t understand what the problem is. I appreciate any help you can provide

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515053/csv-error-iterator-should-return-strings-not-bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `read()` in `s3.get_object()` is bytes, not strings. The `csv. DictReader()` expects strings instead of bytes, and that's why it is failing.

You can decode the result of `read()` into strings using the `decode()` function with the correct encoding. The following would be a fix:

change this

> ```
>     csvcontent = csvfile['Body'].read().split(b'\n')
> ```

to this

> ```
>     csvcontent = csvfile['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
> ```

A good way to debug these problems is to use the `type()` function to check what type your variable is. In your case, you can easily find out the problem by trying `print(type(csvcontent))` - it would show that `csvcontent` indeed is a `byte` type.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small tweak to make it work right:

```
csvcontent = csvfile['Body'].read().decode().split('\n')
```