# How do you edit a CSV row in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Can anyone please help me fix this problem (in python 3):

```
def change(username, new_password):
    filename = 'user.csv'
    tempfile = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)

    with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile, tempfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        fieldnames = ['Name', 'DOB', 'POB', 'Username', 'Password', 'Role', 'Credit']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(tempfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        for row in reader:
            if str(row['Username']) == str(username):
                row['Password'] = new_password
            writer.writerow(row)

    shutil.move(tempfile.name, filename)
```

It always gives me an error saying "iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)". I think it has something to do with the mode or something.... Please help..

Comment: "rb" means read in bytes mode - remove the "b" and just use "r".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iterator+should+return+strings%2C+not+bytes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515053/csv-error-iterator-should-return-strings-not-bytes)

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the file as "rb", which means that it is read in binary mode.
Try setting it to just "r". Furthermore, DictWriter does not write to disk automatically, so remember to save it as well.