# Python excel generation failing in windows

Tags: python, xlwt

Below code is working fine in Unix and while trying to make it work in windows it's failing - 
I am trying to create excel after joining multiple csv files in a directory .
Tab names in excel should be the csv filename -

Below is the code

```
def create_Excel(path,output_file):
 print("Input path is " + path)
 print("Output File name " + output_file )
 wb = xlwt.Workbook()
 for csvfile in glob(os.path.join(path, '*.csv')):
   fpath = csvfile.split("/", 1)
   print ("Current Path " + csvfile )
   fname = fpath[1].split("\\", 2)
   print(str(fname)[1:-1] )
   print ("Current Filename... " + fname[1].split(".",1)[0] )
   ws = wb.add_sheet( fname[1].split(".",1)[0] )
   with open(csvfile, 'rb') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f)
     for r, row in enumerate(reader):
       for c, col in enumerate(row):
         ws.write(r, c, col)
   wb.save(output_file)
```

Error -

```
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

Any suggestion please ? 
Complete output -

```
Output File name INFA_XML.xls
Current Path C:/TEMP/Output\aggregator.csv
'TEMP/Output', 'aggregator.csv'
Current Filename... aggregator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 14, in create_Excel
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

Comment: Why did you use `'rb'` when opening `csvfile`?

Comment: You opened the file in text mode.
Issue already solved at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8519282/13751017

Comment: Does this answer your question? [csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515053/csv-error-iterator-should-return-strings-not-bytes)

Comment: @bileleleuch: File *needs* to be opened in text mode (as your linked answer explains); this code does not do that.

Answer (score 0):

Correct code -

```
def create_Excel(path,output_file):
 print("Input path is " + path)
 print("Output File name " + output_file )
 wb = xlwt.Workbook()
 for csvfile in glob(os.path.join(path, '*.csv')):
  fpath = csvfile.split("/", 1)
  print ("Current Path " + csvfile )
  fname = fpath[1].split("\\", 2)
  print(str(fname)[1:-1] )
  print ("Current Filename... " + fname[1].split(".",1)[0] )
  ws = wb.add_sheet( fname[1].split(".",1)[0] )
  with open(csvfile, 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for r, row in enumerate(reader):
      for c, col in enumerate(row):
        print("Writing to excel .....")
        ws.write(r, c, col)
  wb.save(output_file)
```

Not sure why 'rb' works in Unix but not in Windows