# Writing to a CSV without getting quote marks, escapcehar error

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have an output I am writing to a CSV. I need to add `csv.QUOTE_NONE` but I can't seem to find the right location without it producing an error.

**variable:**

```
variable = ['20', '10', '30,30']
```

*Note: some of the variables I am using will contain strings i.e* `['Test','Output', '100']`

**code:**

```
with open('file.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    writerc = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for item in variable():
        writerc.writerow(item)
```

When using the above code, it produces the following line in the CSV.

`20,10,"30,30"`

The required write is:

`20,30,30,30`

If I use `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` I get an escapechar error `_csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set` - this is resolved if I set an escapechar but this then adds a character in place of the quotation marks.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for replying @PaulRooney That would be easy but I know some of the values are strings. The variable above is an example but some variables I need to use will have `['Test', '20', 'Output']`

Comment: So do you know which columns are expected to be numbers and which strings?

Comment: It has to have quotes in that case because your data is: `20`, `10` and `30,30` and not `20`, `10`, `30` and `30`.

Comment: @PaulRooney sadly not, it depends on the function output from the file. It could be in reverse order too.

Comment: @Tiago thats why I need to use `csv.QUOTE_NONE`

Comment: You pass it when creating the writer `writerc = csv.writer(csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)` see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753704/python-csv-remove-quotes-from-value)

Comment: Thanks @PaulRooney, any idea why I'm getting this error:
`_csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set`

Comment: `writerc = csv.writer(csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='', quotechar='')` see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315366/csv-writer-in-python-with-custom-quoting). Also see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONE)

Comment: @PaulRooney this still produces the same error

Comment: ok you'll have to figure it out for yourself from there :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132447/discussion-between-jam-and-paul-rooney).

Answer (score 0):

You could try further splitting your data before writing it. This would avoid it needing to use quote characters automatically.

It works by creating a new list of values possibly containing multiple new split entries, for example your `'30,30'` would become `['30', '30']`. Next it uses Python's [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=chain#itertools.chain.from_iterable) function to flatten these sub-lists back into a single list which can then be written to your output CSV file.

```
import itertools
import csv

data = [['20', '10', '30,30'], ['Test','Output', '100']]

with open('file.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    for line in data:
        csv_output.writerow(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(v.split(',') for v in line)))
```

This would give you the following `file.csv`:

```
20,10,30,30
Test,Output,100
```

Answer (score 0):

- I think the problem lies in the fact that .csv means Comma-separated
  values, so it treats "," in the value as the `separator` or `delimiter`. That's why the doublequotes are used automatically to escape.
- I suggest you use the pandas library which makes it easier to deal with this issue.

#### Code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'variable' : ['20', '10', '30,30']})
# Note that I use '\t' as the separator instead of ',' and get a .tsv file which
# is essentially the same as .csv file except the separator.
df.to_csv(sep = '\t', path_or_buf='file.tsv', index=False)
```

you can see the differences of using these 2 separators in the [Full script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAU2l.png). Another thing is that, I think your code suggests that you use the `variable`
as the name of the `column`, but your output suggests that you use `variable` as the name of the `row` (or `index`). Anyway, my answer is based on the assumption that you use `variable`
as the name of the `column`. Hope it helps ;)